# MPI Number of processors?

Tags: mpi, processors

Following is my code in MPI, which I run it over a core i7 CPU (quad core), but the problem is it shows me that it's running under 1 processor CPU, which has to be 4.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rank, size;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    printf("Hello world! I am %d of %d\n", rank, size);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

I was wondering if the problem is with MPI library or sth else?

Here is the result that it shows me:

```
Hello world! I am 0 of 1
```

Additional info:
Windows 7 - Professional x64

Comment: how are you running the program?

Comment: You might want to add how you're running the code - typically MPI executables have to be run using a command like `mpirun -np 4 mympiexecutable` to get them to run on 4 processors, for example, but I don't really know Windows MPI versions.

Comment: Note: it is important to put the "-n 4" before the name of the executable. On my machine, if it is after, then it is ignored.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Prima facie it looks like you are running the program directly.  Did you try using `mpiexec -n 2` or `-n 4`?

Comment: yes, I did that and it works fine, but I copied that example from a book which said if for example  you have a dual core CPU, you'd get 2 for the result. 
So here i have a quad core CPU so I should get 4 in result.

Comment: If you run it without explicitly using an mpi wrapper, it will run assuming a single core.

Comment: @Gabriel Lets say you made `test.exe`.  Then, if you just run `test` it will use 1 core.  If you use mpiexec -n 4 test.exe then it will know to use 4 instances.