# Why do OpenMPI programs have to be executed using `mpirun`?

Tags: mpi, openmpi

Why can `MPI`(by which I will mean OpenMPI throughout this post) programs not be executed like any other, and instead have to be executed using `mpirun`?

In other words, why does `MPI` not simply provide headers/packages/... that you can import and then let you be master in your own house, by letting you use `MPI` when and where you want, in your sourcecode, and allowing you to compile your own parallel-processing-included-executables?

I'm really a novice, but for example, I feel like the `-np` argument passed to `mpirun` could easily be fixed in the sourcecode, or could be prompted for by the program itself, or could be read in from a configuration file, or could be simply configured to use all available cores, whose number will be determined by a surrounding scheduler script anyway, or ....
(Of course, you can argue that there is a certain convenience in having `mpirun` do this automatically in some sense, but that hardly justifies, in my view, taking away the coder's possibility to write his own executable.)

For example, I really have little experience, but in Python you can do multiprocessing by simply calling functions of the `multiprocessing` module and then running your script like any other. Of course, `MPI` provides more than Python's `multiprocessing`, but if `MPI` for example has to start a background service, then I still don't understand why it can't do so automatically upon calls of `MPI` functions in the source.

For another possibly stupid example, `CUDA` programs do not require `cudarun`. And for a good reason, since if they did, and if you used both `CUDA` and `MPI` in parts of your program, you would now have to execute `cudarun mpirun ./foo` (or possibly `mpirun cudarun ./foo`) and if every package worked like this, you would soon have to have a degree in computer science to simply execute a program.

All of this is maybe super important, as you can simply ship each of your MPI executables with a corresponding wrapper script, but this is kind of annoying and I would still be interested in why this design choice was made.

Comment: so let's say you want to run on two nodes `A` and `B`, and you simply `a.out  -np 2 --host A,B` on node `A`, how should the second MPI task be spawned on node `B` ?

Comment: You are running `a.out` (with your command line arguments) on the same machine/node as you would run `mpirun a.out`, so they should have the same possibilities to create tasks and processes, right? It might require some messy work within `a.out` to do this, but this work is currently done in `mpirun` anyway, so why can it not be encapsuled in a call to some `MPI`-library function within `a.out`?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet (that comment was for you, let me notify you about it)

Comment: when and how should `a.out` on node `A` spawn `a.out` on node `B` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can spin up processes however you like, you'll need to have some channel to send port information between processes, a command line arg works. I've had to spin up processes manually, but it's far easier and less painful to use a preconstructed communicator.  If you have a good reason, you can do it though.

I have a question where I edited a minimal complete example into the question. The key calls are `MPI_Open_port`, `MPI_Comm_accept`, `MPI_Comm_connect`, and `MPI_Intercomm_merge`. You have to merge the connecting nodes one at a time. If you want to go after this, be sure you have a good idea about the difference between an inter and intracommunicator. Here's the example for you:
 [Trying to start another process and join it via MPI but getting access violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43858346/trying-to-start-another-process-and-join-it-via-mpi-but-getting-access-violation)